# Excel SUMIFS throws #Error for two criterias and =MONTH function

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sumifs

I have the following case in Excel where I have hours based on date and task.
[image]

Based on an `=UNIQUE()` I add all my `tasks` in `I column` and in `J column` I am trying to add the hours based the task and the current month defined on `I2`.

[image]

That formula will throw me the `#Error` but I can't really understand why.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No need = sign when declaring range, should wrap MONTH in ARRAYFORMULA, also $D3:$D and $C:C need to be same length, try =sumifs($D3:D,$C3:$C,$I$4,arrayformula(MONTH($A3:$A)),$I2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try this in **`Sheets`***

```js
=sumifs(D:D,C:C,I4,index(month(A:A)),I$2)
```

- *the parameter `month(A3:A)` is not applied across the whole `A3:A` column_range & is same as writing it as `month(A3)`. You may need to wrap it in an `arrayformula / index` so that it is applied to the whole column_range. Otherwise you will be prompted with `Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size.` error*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a true date to compare date columns for 1st date and last date of criteria month. Try-

```
=SUMIFS($D$3:$D,$C$3:$C,$F4,$A$3:$A,">="&DATE(2023,$G$3,1),$A$3:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2023,$G$3,1),0))
```

[image]

Another good choice could be using `QUERY()` function. This formula will give results without manually putting other formulas. Try-

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(MONTH(A3:A)),C3:D),
"select Col2,sum(Col3)
where Col1=" & G3 & " group by Col2 label Col2 'Tasks', sum(Col3) 'Total'")
```

[image]